# Scroll applied on TextBox while hovering over Label C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, mousewheel, mousehover

Language : C#
Topic : How to detect MouseWheel event and apply it on TextBox while mouse is hovering over a label.

Hi,

I'm making an Windows Form Application and I made it so that when a MouseHover event over multiple labels happens, the text from a textbox is changed. Some messages are longer and require scrolling, but the textbox has to disappear on MouseLeave. I want to make it so that the user can scroll the content of the textbox while hovering over the labels.

Functions used to write in the TextBox

```
    private void writeToInfoTxtBox(string infoToWrite) //write in fieldInfoTxtBox
    {
        enableVisibility(); //func. used to make txtbox visible (among other things)
        fieldInfoTxtBox.Text = infoToWrite;
    }
```

```
private void Label_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    writeToInfoTxtBox("*****");
}
```

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiXb7.png)

I added a capture of the application to make things clearer.

Thank you.

Comment: No end user would ever think to scroll over that label to move the text somewhere else.  Don't do it this way.

Comment: Then how should it be done if this is a bad idea? "Don't do it this way" does not answer my question, but I'm open to suggestions! I thought about tool tips, but I wouldn't know how to implement it and it's more complicated than just changing text in a TextBox.

Comment: You don't have to do anything.  The mousewheel works on the control that has the focus and the scrollbars.  Your textbox scrollbars look wonky though — not sure what's going on with that.

Comment: It's not actually wonky,  the tabControl is on top of it. I tried scrolling while hovering over a label and it doesn't work because the textbox is not in focus when hovering. I just fixed it by setting the focus to the textbox when hovering. The only problem now (which is merely aesthetic) is that the text is highlighted in blue when it is in focus, so I just have to find how to change that. Thank you for setting me on the right track.

Comment: My problem isn't fixed. I can't edit the other fields anymore because focus goes back to the textbox. I will have to find another solution.

Comment: See [Mouse wheel event to work with hovered control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11034348/719186)